# Make bold the header rows in all tables using cls tex document class

Tags: tables, document-classes

I am k novice in LaTeX. I have a tex document that has a cls tex format sheet beside it and create journal articles. Is it possible to make a change that affect all the tables in document have bold header row? If yes which part of cls file should change? There is only one part that refer to tables and figures so I think that the change should be happen here.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
% Graphics, tables and other formatting 
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor} 
\RequirePackage{colortbl} 
\RequirePackage{booktabs} 
 \RequirePackage{algorithm} 
\RequirePackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 
\RequirePackage{changepage} 
\RequirePackage[left=48pt,% right=42pt,% top=46pt,% bottom=60pt,% 
                headheight=15pt,% headsep=10pt,% letterpaper,twoside]
                {geometry}% 
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf},% 
                labelsep=period,% 
                figurename=Fig.,% 
                singlelinecheck=off,% 
                justification=RaggedRight]{caption} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{24pt} % Distance between the two columns of text 
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt} %
```

Paragraph indent

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really have this all in one line?

Comment: If you are talking about submitting to a journal, check first whether it allows this. If yes, you may want to have a look at the first link under "Related" on the right.

Comment: latex has no specific markup for table headers, it is just the first row or rows of a table, so there is no way to specify this globally. The code shown isn't related to the table itself, just the caption text.

Comment: @Amir: So you're interested in formatting the whatever is written between `\begin{tabular}[.]{..}` and the first ``\\`` as being the *header*. So this *excludes* things like `longtable`, `tabularx`, `array`, ...

Comment: @Amir: ...what does this formatting have to look like? What should be done with the content provided by the user? For example, if someone supplies ``\begin{tabular}[.]{..} \hline A & B & C & ... \\ ... \end{tabular}``, what should that be changed into?

Answer (score 1):

The following updates the `tabular` environment and assumes the first line - everything up to the first `\\` - contains the *header*. The *header* is updated to insert whatever you supply to `\setheaderformat{<format>}` at the start of each cell, taking care to always keep `\hline` (or `\toprule`, from [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)) as the first entry within the *header*. `\multicolumn` *header* entries are partially supported (via `\mc`; see below), but nothing else (like multi-line headers, or whatever).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,etoolbox,regexpatch,booktabs}

\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setheaderformat}[1]{\def\header@format{#1}}

\def\format@header#1\\#2\relax{%
  \def\tabular@header{#1\\}%
  \def\tabular@other{#2\relax\relax}%
  \patchcmd{\tabular@header}{\hline}{\hline\TAB}{}{}% \hline support (insert \TAB *after* \hline)
  \patchcmd{\tabular@header}{\toprule}{\toprule\TAB}{}{}% \toprule support (for booktabs)
  \patchcmd{\tabular@other}{\\\relax\relax}{}{}{}% Remove possible ending \\
  \patchcmd{\tabular@other}{\relax\relax}{}{}{}%
}
\RenewEnviron{tabular}[2][c]{%
  \expandafter\format@header\BODY\\\relax% Extract header/other components
  \gdef\TAB{\header@format\gdef\TAB{& \header@format\ignorespaces}\ignorespaces}% Update how \TAB will work
  \xpatchcmd*{\tabular@header}{&}{\TAB}{}{}% Replace all & with \TAB in header
  \begin{oldtabular}[#1]{#2}
    \tabular@header
    \tabular@other
  \end{oldtabular}%
}
\makeatother

\setheaderformat{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{oldtabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
  \hline
\end{oldtabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{oldtabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  a & b & c \\
  \midrule
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
  \bottomrule
\end{oldtabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  a & b & c \\
  \midrule
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% How to manage \multicolumn
\newcommand{\mc}{& \multicolumn}

\setheaderformat{\itshape$\rightarrow$}%
\begin{oldtabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  a & b & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\bfseries c$\leftarrow$} \\
  \midrule
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
  \bottomrule
\end{oldtabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  a & b \mc{1}{r}{\bfseries c$\leftarrow$} \\
  \midrule
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like a better idea to format the headers without such automated intervention, since you don't know what people might put in their headers...

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in ConTeXt this is relatively straight forward to achieve. To make the first row of the table bold, you can use

```
\setupTABLE[row][first][style=bold]
```

However, it is not a good idea to make this change globally because there may be instances where you want the first row not to be bold. Instead, it is better to define a new setup and use that in tables:

```
\startsetups table:header
    \setupTABLE[row][first][style=bold]
\stopsetups
```

and then use it as:

```
\startTABLE[setups=table:header]
```

Here is a complete example showing the result.

```
\startsetups table:header
  \setupTABLE[each][each][frame=off, offset=0.25ex, rulethickness=1.5pt]
  \setupTABLE[row][first][style=bold, topframe=on, bottomframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[row][last] [bottomframe=on]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startTABLE[setups=table:header]
  \NC Type \NC First \NC Second \NC Third \NC \NR
  \NC A    \NC B     \NC C      \NC D     \NC \NR
  \NC A    \NC B     \NC C      \NC D     \NC \NR
  \NC A    \NC B     \NC C      \NC D     \NC \NR
  \NC A    \NC B     \NC C      \NC D     \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Unfortunately, as you have found out, none of the table mechanisms in LaTeX provide such a separation between content and presentation in tables.